# Read results from H2DB

Tags: java, sql, database, h2

I have a problem with reading the content of the rows in the database.
I want to show the information (in the console for the moment) about  the employee with given position and name. I have built the path ,started the database in H2 but I am not sure I have used PreparedStatement right .

> Table "MyTable" not found

I removed the try/catch to be more readable.

```
static public void  Search (JButton a , JFormattedTextField name, JComboBox<String> b ) {
    a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e ) {
            Connection con = null;

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test" + "sa" + "");

            Statement stm = null;
            String ime = name.getText();// reads the name 
            String poz = (String) b.getSelectedItem();// reads the position

            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");

            String sql1 = String.format("SELECT * FROM  RABOTNICI  WHERE IME = '%s' OR POZICIA = '%s'", ime, poz);
            PreparedStatement prstm = null;

            prstm = con.prepareStatement(sql1);

            ResultSet rs = null;

            rs = prstm.executeQuery(sql1);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> jdbc:h2:tcp:...

You are using TCP connection but not starting H2 TCP server like this:
http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server

Normally H2 database is used as embedded without TCP server like this:
http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#connecting_using_jdbc

> jdbc:h2:/path/to/dbfile

Answer (score 0):

I think you had some sources of information and something went wrong down the way.

- The way you created a preparedStatement, even if it's parsed correctly, is prone to SQL Injections.
  You should first create the statement and only then inject the values.

  ```
  String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM  RABOTNICI  WHERE IME = ? OR POZICIA = ?"
  PreparedStatement prstm = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
  prstm.setString(1, ime);
  prstm.setString(2, poz);
  ```

  Please consult this [doc page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for correct usage of PreparedStatements
- Also, getConnection's argument looks a bit messed up.

  ```
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test" + "sa" + "");
  ```
- The following line should appear before the connection creation.

  ```
  Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
  ```

  I suggest using this [tutorial](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#connecting_using_jdbc) for instruction regarding connection to H2 DB
- And last, I'm not sure how do you get the error about "MyTable" its never mentioned in your code snippet.

My code quotes were not tested but I believe are clear enough to get the idea.

Comment: Thank you ! I`ll take a look at the link you gave . I used "My Table " as an example :) . I get the idea i just needed some guidelines

Comment: also, as @haba713 mentioned in another answer: 
You should either start a H2 DB apart from your application, or start it from within you app. But it should be alive and accessible, whether from TCP or in-mem

Comment: Yes i start it from the terminal , then connect the application to it . In my other application which writes data into the database i have no problem , everything is working fine .